# Adobe ExtendScript http request fails: no shared cipher

Tags: nginx, ssl, cipher

For my [Adobe CEP project](https://github.com/jenstroeger/Bookalope-CEP) I try to call to a REST API over https from the Javascript side:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'https://***/api/books', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic NDI5MDk...');
xmlhttp.send(null);
if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

The code triggers the following output in the console:

```
net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

Looking at the nginx server log on the other side, there is only a single error message:

```
2016/09/29 11:25:34 [info] 7048#7048: *4396957 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher) while SSL handshaking, client: **.**.**.**, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Other clients have no problems connecting to the server. The web server is very stable and well maintained, runs TSL 1.2 and supports all secure ciphers:

```
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 4096) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 4096) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 4096) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A
```

What is happening here? What would be the appropriate way to investigate, better yet to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi Jens, you wrote that you started this code from your Adobe ExtendScript, but as far as I know there is no XMLHttpRequest() object for Extendscript. *I would be very interested if that is really an option*. I got "XMLHttpRequest does not have a constructor" error, trying your code as an ExtendScript now.
Perhaps you were referring to a normal javascript js file in a CEP (html panels) solution, and that you raised an event from the ExtendScript to start your request?

Comment: @AndreasJansson, yes, my bad, correcting the writeup. I’ve used the Javascript side in a CEP project and not the ExtendScript side. However, you may be interested in this solution: https://github.com/grefel/restix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that InDesign's Javascript side is unable to establish a connection using TLS 1.2. After enabling TLS 1 and 1.1 on our server (while maintaining our A+ rating), everything worked.